# “On your own block”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

> You belong on your own block, where I can whistle for you.

I am totally confused by “***belong on your own block***”, could anyone please help me understand this sentence? Your help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please remember to supply adequate context, and an indication of your initial research efforts. Where is this sentence quoted from? What are the surrounding sentences? What seems illogical or unnatural about the words or the phrasing to you?

Comment: @choster Thanks! Actually, It’s just an example. See [here](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/somebody-can-whistle-for-something)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure without more context but I would interpret that as:

> You should be on your own street block (*ie* near home) so you can come when I call for you.

The reference you give is a valid use for "whistle for something" but I don't think it applies to this sentence.  Again, more context is needed.